# Cannot import Tkinter font object from module

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, python-import

I've got a feeling this will end in a facepalm, but I just can't puzzle out why this `import x from y` scenario isn't working for me.  As a starting point, take the following module `main.py`:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
__metaclass__ = type
#Create widgets
root = tk.Tk()
fntPlainText = tkFont.Font(family='Courier New',size=10)
lblDisplay = tk.Label(root, relief=tk.SUNKEN,
                      font=fntPlainText,
                      width=30,height=5,
                      text='This is a test!')
#Do layout
lblDisplay.grid(padx=5,pady=5)
#Begin app
tk.mainloop()
```

This runs normally and puts up a small label with the expected content:

[image]

So now I want to move the definition of this `Font` object to a separate module, so I can share it among multiple applications.  My updated code modules are `fonts1.py`:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
__metaclass__ = type
fntPlainText = tkFont.Font(family='Courier New',size=10)
```

...and `main1.py`:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from fonts1 import fntPlainText
__metaclass__ = type

#Create widgets
root = tk.Tk()
lblDisplay = tk.Label(root, relief=tk.SUNKEN,
                      font=fntPlainText,
                      width=30,height=5,
                      text='This is a test!')
#Do layout
lblDisplay.grid(padx=5,pady=5)
#Begin app
tk.mainloop()
```

But when I run `main1.py`, I get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\experiments\investigations\tk\main1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from fonts1 import fntPlainText
  File "G:\Python\experiments\investigations\tk\fonts1.py", line 5, in <module>
    fntPlainText = tkFont.Font(family='Courier New',size=10)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\tkFont.py", line 89, in __init__
    tk.call("font", "create", self.name, *font)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call'
```

From Googling and experimenting, I found enough to know that something's going wrong with the assignment of `fntPlainText`, but (again) I can't figure out what it is.  The biggest puzzle of the whole situation is that when I pare down `fonts1.py` to simply define `fntPlainText` as a tuple--

Modified `fonts1.py`:

```
fntPlainText = ('Courier New',10)
```

Running `main1.py` now completes normally and paints the same window as `main.py`.

If it matters, the environment is Python 2.7.x running on Windows 7.

Comment: it sounds like you're trying to create the font before creating the root window.

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Comment below to Matt explains what threw me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a root window (tk.Tk()) before creating the font. If you move your

```
from fonts1 import fntPlainText
```

below the tk.Tk() call it should work as you expect.

Comment: yes, that's working.  And now I think I see why I'm getting the traceback for this scenario, where I wasn't getting a traceback for other similar scenarios.  In my "real" application I have several external modules that define various customized Tkinter widgets, but in all cases, those widgets are wrapped up as a class definition... hence, they import just fine because the widget doesn't actually exist until it's instantiated (which, in my "real" application, doesn't happen until well after I created the root window).

Comment: If `fonts1` contained `def make_plain_font(root): return tkFont.Font(root, family='Courier New',size=10)`, then importing would not create the font and you could put the import back at the top where it belongs..